# How to GRANT SELECT PRIVILEGES on table with wild card with psql postgres

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have tables' names that start with underscore '_XXXXXXX' among other tables. I need to create a user that  can only do a query on these '_XXXX" tables (nothing else)  **without** the possibility of viewing/finding the other tables (not starting with '_XXXXX').

How can i do that in postgres psql?:

I tried

```
  GRANT SELECT ON TABLE "_*" TO username;
```

i get the following:

ERROR:  relation "_*" does not exist

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

when I execute this code in PgAdmin4 query editor:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  r record;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN SELECT c.relname,
                  n.nspname
                  FROM pg_class c
                       INNER JOIN pg_namespace n
                                  ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
                  WHERE n.nspname = 'Schemas'
                        AND c.relkind = 'r'
                        AND c.relname LIKE '$_%'
                                           ESCAPE '$' LOOP
    EXECUTE 'GRANT SELECT ON "' || r.nspname || '"."' || r.relname || '" TO kpidata;';
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

i get the following response and nothing changes (still have the same access rights to all for the created user 'kpidata'). I am sure it is me who is not understanding how things work

[image]

my db structure is the following:

[image]

Comment: You should ask this kind of question on https://dba.stackexchange.com. On the same site problably you find the answer. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104172/postgresql-grant-all-on-mutliple-tables-using-like

Comment: A user that can connect will always be able to find the other tables. By using privileges you can only block access to the data within the tables. If you really need to hide the other tables you might want to create a second database and make tables from first accessible inside second database by using [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/postgres-fdw.html) however this will reduce performance.

Comment: @Eelke, thank you. you are right. Privileges are revoked. but i still can see all tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `DO` block looping over all table with names beginning with underscore, build the statement for it an execute the statement.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  r record;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN SELECT c.relname,
                  n.nspname
                  FROM pg_class c
                       INNER JOIN pg_namespace n
                                  ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
                  WHERE n.nspname = 'public'
                        AND c.relkind = 'r'
                        AND c.relname LIKE '$_%'
                                           ESCAPE '$' LOOP
    EXECUTE 'GRANT SELECT ON "' || r.nspname || '"."' || r.relname || '" TO username;';
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: sorry, i am not familiar with loops in psql. I tried to copy the code and changing schema name and username, but it seems i am doing something wrong. the statement is not being executed in psql shell

Comment: I have still access to all tables !

Comment: @Gerad: Maybe the schema name should also be included in the statement. See my edit. Other than that "not being" executed doesn't tell me much... any error message!?

Comment: Hi and thank you for your patience. I am new to postgres. so when I log in in psql console (using iMac) , and paste the code (with the required changes) and press return. I got DO. when using pgAdmin4 it always show the whole table list. So just to make sure I got it: schema means the name of the database, am I correct?

Comment: @Gerard: Nah, name of the schema. If you didn't do anything extra you're likely in the `public` schema. The schema here is in there to filter for tables, in internal schemes, that also may begin with an underscore but which you likely don't want to target.

Comment: @Gerard: I use pgAdmin III (the Query editor) and have no problems executing the code. But I'm neither familiar with the psql console nor with pgAdmin 4, sorry. But I cannot imagine there'd be something totally different there.

Comment: I used the pgAdmin explain/analyze feature to run the sql and it gives :ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DO"
LINE 1: ...rue,VERBOSE False,COSTS False,TIMING False,BUFFERS False) DO
                                                                     ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 89

Comment: @Gerard: `EXPLAIN` is for queries, to get the execution plan, which tells what tables, indexes and methods were used to compute a query result. You cannot `EXPLAIN` a `DO` block. And even if, I thought you wanted it executed.

Comment: @Gerard: OK, I can see in your edit of the question you also executed it. But instead of the schema name `public` (which is the one as I can see from the other screenshot) you used `Schemas`. That's wrong, use `public`. I edited the answer and put the schema name `public` in there.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help